# After trying to start a Java Applet, (how) can I detect that a user declined it?

Tags: java, applet

Is there a way for me to detect (and then give a more user-friendly message than the dialog saying "BlockedException" or whatever) that a user denied an applet the permission to run?

Answer (score 0):

- Set a redirect in the applet page, pointing to your 'friendly message'.
- Write a JS function that can cancel it.
- Call the JS function from the applet once it is loading.

Comment: a redirect, with a timer you mean? that sounds fragile

Comment: (chuckle) If you want something that is 'not fragile', use a technology that is 'not an applet'.